# Объединить два массива в один и конвертировать в JSON

Tags: php, массивы

Есть два метода одного класса, один выводит продукты, второй категории:

```
class Content {
    // подключение к БД

    public function get_cat() {
        $query = $this->db->query("SELECT * FROM categories WHERE id=1");
        while ($row = $query->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
            $id = $row['id'];
            $username = $row['title'];

            $return_arr[] = array(
                "id_cat" => $id,
                "title_cat" => $username,
            );
        }

        return $return_arr;
    }

    public function get_products() {
        $query = $this->db->query("SELECT * FROM products WHERE parent=1");
        while ($row = $query->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC))
        {
            $id = $row['id'];
            $username = $row['title'];

            $return_arr[] = array(
                "id_prod" => $id,
                "title_prod" => $username
            );
        }

        return $return_arr;
    }
}
```

Как из этих двух массивов получить один в формате json?

Comment: @The art of being alive, из двух нужен один, где будут id_cat, title_cat, id_prod,  title_prod

Comment: у них есть общие ключи?

Comment: @The art of being alive, что бы примерно такого вида был [{"id_cat":"691","title_cat":"категория 1"},"id_cat":"692","title_cat":"категория 2","id_prod":"1691","title_prod":"продукт 1"},"id_prod":"1692","title_prod":"продукт 2"}]

Comment: ниже дал ответ.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Если я правильно вас понял, то следующее решение:

*(массивы для примера)*

```
$array1 = [
    ['id_cat' => 1, 'title_cat' => 2],
    ['id_cat' => 3, 'title_cat' => 4]
];

$array2 = [
    ['id_prod' => 1, 'title_prod' => 2],
    ['id_prod' => 3, 'title_prod' => 4]
];

foreach($array1 as $key => $value) {
    $result[$key] = array_merge($array1[$key], $array2[$key]);
}

echo json_encode($result);
```

https://3v4l.org/IgMhU

Comment: да это оно, array_merge принимает только 2 параметра, а если мне еще третий и четвертый массив нужно будет добавить?

Comment: @аноним, нет массивов может быть множество. указывайте так: `array_merge($a, $b, $c, $d ...)`, суть думаю поняли.

Comment: array_merge($array1[$key], $array2[$key],$array3[$key],$array4[$key]); так можно будет?

Comment: @аноним, конечно

Comment: если в $array2 добавить больше элементов, то все равно будет выводить ровно столько сколько их в $array1, как это исправить?

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/102549/discussion-between-the-art-of-being-alive-and-).